# Creating relational database tables

Tags: database, relational-database

I'm creating a website for my Corporation .

The database contains the following information:

- About the staff of the Agency (Name, position);
- About the trip (country, city, hotel, whether you need a visa, the date of the trip, the cost. The cost depends on the type of hotel, the type of food (whether it is all inclusive or not), from the quality of your room, the number of days on the trip, the date when you ordered the trip;

I have no idea of how many tables to create and what should be the relationship with them . Help me in understanding this problem .

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described, create the following tables.

- An Employee table for the Agency Staff (Name, Position, etc.)
- A Trip table containing information about each trip.  Here you could capture trip costs and other information.
- A Hotel Table, containing information about the hotels.

You will want to define a relationship between each of these 3 tables.

```
Employee.EmployeeID --> Trip.EmployeeID
Hotel.HotelID --> Trip.HotelID
```